# Tokenizing a string in C

Tags: c, token

I'm trying to store a string with a first and last name from a string into a struct but I'm getting (warning: passing argument 1 of strcpy makes pointer from integer without a cast), and I'm not sure on where to put strcpy tried putting it in the while loop got the error which makes sense. But not sure on where to place strcpy 
**EDITED**

```
 struct trip

    {
     char first_name;
     char last_name;

    }
    int main(void)
    {
     struct trip travel[12];
    }

    char input_name(struct trip travel[MAXTRIP], int index)
    {
      int name_read, length; 
      int name_bytes = 100;
      char *name, *word;                 

      getchar();
      printf("Please enter name:\n");

      name = (char *)malloc(name_bytes + 1);
      name_read = getline (&name, &name_bytes, stdin);

      word = strtok(name, ",");
      while (word != NULL)
        {
          strcpy(travel[index].first_name, word);
          word = strtok(NULL, ",");

        }


    }
```

Comment: What is `word`?  What is `name`?  How have you declared your variables?  Are you actually getting that error message?  `strcpy` isn't used anywhere in your program.

Comment: Please post your actual code. There is no `strcpy` shown above and you don't show what most of your variables are.

Comment: In your struct you can only hold two characters: one for first name and another for last name. If you want to hold more characters define an array or a pointer to array (char *) and allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: Like wenuxas says, your struct defines `first_name` and `last_name` as single characters. The error is from the character being promoted to integer when passed to `strcpy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the (**MANY**) errors in your code, you are putting the `strcpy()` in the right place.

However, you are not calling it with the correct arguments: `strcpy()` needs 2 arguments.
Basically, both are of type `char*`; you are passing a `char` and a `char*` and that is why the compiler complains (for the compiler the `char` behaves like an `int` so it says "strcpy makes pointer from integer").

**You need to review your data structure and pass the right `char*`s to `strcpy()`.**

Comment: Yea I was looking over my notes and seems like I'm passing it in wrong.